# File preview in right-most column?

Tags: pantheon-files

Is it possible to have a file preview for "known formats" (e.g. image, PDF, ODT) in the right-most column in columnar view?

[image]

I do already have thumbnails enabled, but am looking for a bigger preview on a per file basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This suggestion is periodically raised but is (so far) regarded as contrary to elementaryos design policy I am afraid.  See for example https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/438

Elementary native apps are intended to open quickly enough to make a preview unnecessary as the delay in generating the preview would be comparable with the delay in opening the app. Native apps are intended be as simple as possible.  In most cases the combination of file name and thumbnail (which can be as large as 256px at maximum zoom) is enough to identify the contents of the file.